# Issues with inheritance when implementing Grails services

Tags: grails

So, is it not recommended using an inheritance-approach when implementing Grails services? I went through a simple service specialization pattern understanding that all would work in a transparent way, but I started to go into trouble regarding transaction management under the spring/grails hood. Issues happen when a method from the specialized class calls a method from the inherited class (both concrete services themselves):

```
@Transactional
public class MammalService {

  public mammalMethod() {
  }

}

@Transactional
public class DogService extends MammalService {

   public dogMethod() {
       mammmalMethod()
   }

}
```

It comes that when the inherited method is called from the specialized one,  `org.springframework.transaction.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate()` constructor is fired (by the spring/grails transaction AOP) with a null `transactionManager` argument, which causes some `NullPointerException` moreover.

Has anyone used such approach with services? Am I missing something?

PS: Curiously, I tried changing the `@grails.transaction.Transactional` annotation by the `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` and the `NullPointerException` ceased from happening. (Nevertheless, it didn't point to a nice solution, since other side effects started to happen with my pool management).

UPDATE1: While debugging, I can see TWO variables with the same name transactionManager inside my specialized service (something that doesn't happen when inspecting the concrete superclass).

[image: error]

I'm opening a more specific issue at [Duplicated transactionManager property in Grails service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740143/duplicated-transactionmanager-property-in-grails-service)

Comment: I have extended services before but not for transactional reasons and not specifically inheritance. Wschat plugin extends services for using common features.  Are you sure the pool management issues are due to extending . I would look at firstly does the entire service need to be transaction based. Or are there only specific calls that requires @ transactional. As a test I would also remove overall @ transactional and add to each call method that then means it gets triggered when called.  Maybe your domain objects should extend instead then have save(Dog dog) save(Cat cat) as mamalservice

Comment: The pool management issues are not due to extending, but rather because I tried to substitute the grails transaction annotations by spring ones (just for testing). My services are database-centric, so they must be transactional. I tried removing the transactional annotations from the class and left it in (almost all) methods, but sadly the NullPointerException hasn't gone. Tks anyway.

Comment: This is two separate issues. I have left a comment on the other and in regards to what you are trying to do here, I think it is the domain classes you should be extending not services. Take a look at extending abstract domain classes vs non abstract. This then creates different data structures for your database. The service usually in extended domain classes can be 1 for the overall shared changes so save(Mamal input) and save(Cat input) where any mamal hits cat and hits Mamal save blocks so it hits cat to do cat stuff then mamal to do mamal stuff that all other mamals do...

Comment: Tks again for your feedback, @vahid. Unfortunately, there are many business rules specific to the specialized domain class and the base service wouldn't deal with that nicely. Maybe the only solution is to convert the specialization pattern to completely independent services calling each other. This would be a pity for my architecture, I must say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Solved by removing @Transaction from specialized service classes and
>   methods, keeping them only on the inherited service class and its methods.

```
@Transactional
public class MammalService {

  @Transactional(readonly=true)
  public mammalMethod() {
  }

}

//Don't annotate with @Transactional - rely on the super class declaration
public class DogService extends MammalService {

   //Don't annotate with @Transactional - rely on the super class transactional declaration
   public dogMethod() {
       mammmalMethod()
   }

}
```

It seems that, for specialized service classes, the transaction routines try to re-inject the `transactionManager` attribute, resulting in two attributes with the same name and one of them null. Also, annotating overrided methods raises an StackOverflowException.

Comment: @graemerocher says the issue is fixed in grails 3